# Happy First Anniversary Ask Ubuntu!!! 

Tags: discussion

For those of you who have been around this site for one year or more (in other words, you have the [yearling badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/13/yearling)), you will most definitely remember what transpired exactly one year ago (10/10/10):

- [Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) was released
- [Ask Ubuntu went public!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ask-ubuntu-stack-exchange-site-out-of-beta-new-awesome-domain/)

According to UTC time, that day was exactly one year ago. A lot of questions have been asked since then and a lot of excellent answers provided. A lot of changes have made their way into the site as well - not only changes in the way the site operates, but changes in policy too (many of which were decided right here on Meta).

So, basically all I wanted to say is...

### Happy Birthday, Ask Ubuntu!<sup>*</sup>

http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/askubuntu.png

<sub>* May this be the first of many more to come!</sub>

Comment: P.S. We need a site banner announcing the good news.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Cake!]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a digital cake piece can go to all members and a thank you card for being part of  askubuntu. Askubuntu family maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Happy Birthday, Ask Ubuntu! and go for other year..